# Passing Javascript Variable in Form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am new to javascript and i am having a hard time resolving one problem in my script.
I want to pass the variable "outVal" when i click the submit form to a php script.
The value of "outVal" will be obtained from the value of "output" in the script.
I do not know how i can pass the value of "output" to "outVal".
I have searched for solutions and tried every on of it but it doesn't work.
Maybe someone can help me find a proper solution for this.
My code is below:
Note: both codes are in the same file.

HTML:

```
<{includeq file="db:frontend_breadcrumbs.tpl"}>
<div>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<script src="./assets/js/jsoneditor.min.js"></script>

<div class='row'>
    <div class='span8 col-md-8 columns eight large-8'>  
        <form action="./applyProcess.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label for="file">Filename:</label>
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
            <input type="hidden" name="hashAlgo" value="<{$hashAlgo}>">
            <input type="hidden" name="tempDirName" value="<{$tempDirName}>">
            <input type="hidden" name="op" value="upload">
            <input type="hidden" id="outVal" name="outVal">
        </form>

        <div id='editor_holder'></div>
    </div>
</div>

    <textarea id='output' style='width: 100%; height: 300px; font-family: monospace;' class='form-control'></textarea>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
(function() {
    var jsoneditor;
    // Divs/textareas on the page
    document.getElementById('output').style.display = 'none';
    var $output = document.getElementById('output');
    var $editor = document.getElementById('editor_holder');
    var $outVal =  document.getElementById('outVal');


    var $jsonschema = <{$applyProcessJsonSchema}>;

    var reload = function(keep_value) {
        var $startvalue = (jsoneditor && keep_value)? jsoneditor.getValue() : <{$applyProcessRequestData}>;
        if(jsoneditor) jsoneditor.destroy();
        jsoneditor = new JSONEditor($editor,{
            ajax: true,
            schema: $jsonschema,
            startval: $startvalue,
            disable_array_add: true,
            disable_array_delete: false,
            disable_array_reorder: true,
            disable_edit_json: true,
            disable_properties: true
        });

        // When the value of the editor changes, update the JSON output and validation message
        jsoneditor.on('change',function() {
            var json = jsoneditor.getValue();
            $output.value = JSON.stringify(json,null,2);
            var validation_errors = jsoneditor.validate();
            if(validation_errors.length) {
                var error = JSON.stringify(validation_errors,null,2);
                alert("Validation Error" + error);
                reload(true);
            }
        });
        $outVal.value = $output.value;
    };
    reload();
})();

function applySubmit() {
    var $output = document.getElementById('output');
    var $outVal =  document.getElementById('outVal');
    $outVal.value = $output.value;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Having `name` in your input elements will make it so they are sent on form submission (note it gets the `value`). Did you try `$_POST["outVal"]` with just setting some default `value`?

Comment: oh sorry, i am not clear with what i want to do. i want to get the value of "output" in javascript then pass it to "outVal" then i will use $_POST['outVal'] in the php file when i want to get it. i have updated my question. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: i tried sending a default value for "outVal" and i can get the value when i use the $_POST['outVal'].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

before you submit the form call the `applysubmit` function, it modify your form value, pls check the code below, added `onsubmit` event to form element,

```
<form action="./applyProcess.php" method="post" onsubmit="return applySubmit();" enctype="multipart/form-data">


function applySubmit() {
        var $output = document.getElementById('output');
        var $outVal =  document.getElementById('outVal');
        $outVal.value = $output.value;
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: i tried your solution but i didn't get the value of "outVal" when i used $_POST['outVal'] in php file.

Comment: try var_dump($_POST) or print_r($_POST) from your php

Comment: i tried var_dump($_POST) and the result is this: `array(5) { ["submit"]=> string(6) "Upload" ["hashAlgo"]=> string(7) "SHA-256" ["tempDirName"]=> string(56) "/var/www/html/xoops/modules/frontend/cache/5426b2587c138" ["op"]=> string(6) "upload" ["outVal"]=> string(0) "" }`

Comment: modify this function, so that form will not be submitted, u can inspect the value of textarea and hidden field, pls check
 function applySubmit() {
        var $output = document.getElementById('output');
        var $outVal =  document.getElementById('outVal');
        $outVal.value = $output.value;
        return false;
    }

Comment: i did get a value for "outVal". i used alert and printed the value of "outVal" and it is `{ "ProcessApplicationInfo": { "ProcessApplicationList": [ { "ProcessId": "process#01", "InputParameter": { "sign_type": "xxxx" } }, { "ProcessId": "process#02", "InputParameter": { "enc_type": "xxxx" } } ] } }` but when i try accessing it in php file i still don't get the data.

Comment: i found the cause of the problem. it is because i only put a snippet of my code in here. i also have a form that has the same name "outVal". So when i changed to a different name, i can now get the data. This answer is correct.